Is Kimetsu no Yaiba: Infinity Castle the end of the anime?
Today was the last episode of Kimetsu no Yaiba: Hashira Geiko-hen, where they start the battle against the antagonist of the series, so it's clear it's close to the end of the anime. On the same day, Crunchyroll released the official trailer for Demon Slayer: Kimetsu no Yaiba Infinity Castle. Is this movie trilogy the end of the anime?

Logically speaking, yes.

It probably is. If the Demon Slayer: Infinity Castle Arc movies are each around 2 hours long, three movies would cover about the same amount of content as 18 TV episodes. The Infinity Castle Arc is also the final arc in the manga.

!! Major spoilers ahead. Proceed with maximum caution!!
There is a large probability that the Infinity Castle Arc is the end of the anime.

 After all, the whole plot is about slaying demons, and Kibutsuji Muzan is the ultimate demon. In the Infinity Castle Arc, Muzan was defeated and ultimately killed. Muzan's death meant the annihilation of the whole demon race, with the exception of Yushiro. Thus, we can safely assume that since the main goal is accomplished, the series will end. Additionally, sadly, during the fight with Muzan and/or the rest of the Upper Rank Demon Blood Moons, five Hashira, namely Obanai Iguro, Shinobu Kocho, Mitsuri Kanroji, Muichiro Tokito, and Gyomei Himejima all died. With nearly all the Hashira and a large portion of the major supporting characters gone, the story plot would've had a hard time building up another cast of characters. In the manga, it is also stated that the Demon Slayer Corps was disbanded by Kiriya Ubuyashiki, thus the organization that bonded all of the demon slayers together no longer exists. The main protagonist, Tanjiro Kamado, suffered irrecoverable injuries that prevented him from further fighting. Finally, the manga ends with the Infinity Castle Arc, so it is quite plausible that the anime will end here as well, given that Ufotable does not have a tendency to extend the story even further than the manga.


I don't remember which studio made "Erased", but there was a portion of that anime that ran ahead of the manga, and they made a few critical story development choices that probably affected the outcome of the story beyond what the author may have intended. I do not remember if the anime ended differently than the manga. I think Erased should be a cautionary tale to encourage policies of never running ahead.

@AustinOverton I agree with you that manga-adapted anime should never run ahead of the original manga. Just to note here, Erased (Japanese: 僕だけがいない街, Hepburn: Boku dake ga Inai Machi) was adapted into anime by A-1 Pictures.
